# No-network/Wlan Connection in 22.04 after upgrading

Tags: networking

After Upgrading from 20.04 up to 22.04 there is no more network-connection. What can I do?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like something went wrong during the upgrade and one package that was not upgraded is not working properly in 22.04.

Comment: Please edit the output of `sudo lshw -C network
` into your question